# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in messgaebox of tkinter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Getting error when executing the below code:

```
#other codes

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

#othercodes

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)

#other codes

def net_connection_error():
    #print(dir(messagebox))
    messagebox.INFO(
        "info",
        "No Connection!"
    )

#other codes

net_connection_error()

#other codes

root.mainloop()
```

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `messagebox.INFO` is a string (print it), and you are using it as a function. You want the `messagebox.showinfo(...)` instead.

note: as a convention, in most frameworks, uppercase variables are usually string or numeric constants. You'll rarely find a library where `INFO` could be a function.